# Firebase Auth missing email address

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() (Federated Google-Sign in provided by Firebase)

Most of the time I am getting back the logged in user's email address. But sometimes its resulting null. I can see the user has a gmail.com address but it still does not return.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add more of your code (_[not your whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_)? From what you've posted it's impossible for us to help - your single line of code you provide [matches what is given in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) so I suspect you're doing something else wrong - maybe **when** you're calling it... the first thing that comes to my mind when you say it is `null` only _sometimes_ is that it's probably related to an issue with some asynchronous code you wrote.

Comment: I don't have anything asynchronous. Its a simple one-liner I use to display the email address and also use it in the developer payload for in-app purchases. Is getEmail() asynchronous? I didn't think so...